# Are Mr. PBH, Noob-noob and Stealy of the same (alien) species?

Tags: rick-and-morty, character-similarity

Has it ever been revealed (or mentioned) by the creators of *Rick and Morty* that whether Mr. PBH (Poopybutthole), and Stealy belong to the same species (alien or otherwise)?

Additionally, although Noob-noob is a bit distinctive (in skin tone), is it ever possible that even he too, belongs to the same species as Mr. PBH and Stealy?

[image]

Looking for answers either hinted in the show and/or the interviews of the Roiland/Harmon.

Comment: Mr PBH and Stealy seems to be from the same species but I'm not qure Noobnoob qualifies. Different skin tone, irregular eyes, ... Other than the pill-shaped head and the general draw style of R&M, they don't have much in common. Unless Noobnoob has e.g. mixed heritage or medical abnormalities.

Comment: https://rickandmorty.fandom.com/wiki/Mr._Poopybutthole%27s_species - The short answer is maybe.

Answer (score -1):

Mr. PBH (Mr. Poopybutthole), Stealy and NoobNoob are from the same planet but are simply different forms of the same species. It’s similar to humans and our individual differences.

All variations of creatures like Mr. PBH are depicted to have short, stumpy legs which begs the idea that unlike humans whose legs grow to become taller, in Mr. PBH species their arms grow longer instead. With that in mind NoobNoob and Mr. PBH would be considered average height members of their species while Stealy would be considered tall. Seeing as their species lacks the ability for leg growth Stealy would probably be seen as “wide” instead of “tall” since their measurements for growth would be for width instead of length.

Imagine a doctors scale for a physical appointment would have a pole spread horizontally to measure their arms instead of vertically to measure their height.

NoobNoob seems confident in his understanding of Rick’s jokes and looked down upon because he appears to be lacking a superpower and therefore looked at as one of the “learning disabled kids we do photo ops with” that Vance referred to Morty as.

While NoobNoob’s face may be deformed by the markers of his planet his appearance is too similar to Mr. PBH and Stealy for him to not be considered one of them. Especially when you consider the fact that this show is known for being meticulous about the animation of specific characters both for comedic effect and earlier season callbacks.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you have any sources you can cite for this?  The question was specifically asking about what had been revealed in the show or by the creators.

Comment: Considering Mr Poopybutthole is *likely* an alien parasite who doesn't look like that image, you cannot compare him to other "yellow pillhead" creatures. Yes, Beth shoots him, but part of the joke is that he was never part of the family before yet he shares much of the memories -- just like a parasite. It's inconsistent, but all of R&M is inconsistent.